# can i put a space between the content and the arrow in an html select drop down?

Tags: html, css

i have a select drop down, which has the word "girl" as an option.

The problem is that the "l" of girl is *very* close to the arrow drop-down thing on the select. How can i put a bit more "space" between the word/content (all of the options, i mean.  I don't feel the need to *just* target the word "girL") and the little arrow?

I have tried putting a space after "girl", but this has no effect (ie the problem is still extant).

Here is what it looks like (kind of)

```
sex:    |boy |v|
        |girl|
```

here is what i want:

```
sex:    |boy  |v|
        |girl |
```

yes, i know pretty much everyone here knows what i'm on about. it is just kind of fun to draw the dropdown with pipes!

PS html or css, i am indifferent to the method of the solution!

Comment: have you tried setting a width to the select item? Or applying padding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe, this is too late, but, I am posting it as information for next visitors.

1. Setting the `width` is not solution for every case. Flexible width is useful sometimes.
2. `Padding-right` is not solution too, because it only adds space between arrow and
   right border, but not between text and arrow.
3. For static list item, adding `&nbsp;` at the tail of each row is best solution. But if you do it dynamically, Google Chrome shows it as text instead of special character.
4. For dynamic change, following works great:

   `option.text = itemtext + String.fromCharCode(160);`

Comment: for anyone reading this in 2021+, using spaces to pad out like this is straight up barbaric. Use padding.

Answer (score 0):

Hey now give to `padding right` to **select tag** as like this

```
   select{
    padding-right:40px; // as your requirement give to padding-right 
    }
```

Live demo http://tinkerbin.com/vPS8tXNJ

Comment: its never too late to help!

Comment: that website is linked as dangerous from uBlock Origin

Answer (score -2):

just use

```
&nbsp;
```

to add a space after it.... if you do need it in css...

```
padding-right: 10px;
```